# Two wlan connections at once

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Is it possible to connect with two wlan access points or ad hoc networks at once? In best case, using network manager.

Or is this permitted by hardware design?

I like to have another connection to another local service with less latency than my WLAN/WAN router offers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an error of operating system,it show 2 connection but it currently using only one off 2 connection. however, you can turn off one of this.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. I think you misunderstood the question; it seems not to be an answer to what is being asked.